# How to represent the nested lists in lists in lists etc. in a graph?

Tags: python, nltk

Currently I'm trying to visualize part of wordnet in a graph using networkx. The output that is returned by `nltk.wordnet.synsets('girl')[0].tree(lambda s:s.hypernyms())` looks like:

```
[Synset('girl.n.01'),
 [Synset('woman.n.01'),
  [Synset('adult.n.01'),
   [Synset('person.n.01'),
    [Synset('causal_agent.n.01'),
     [Synset('physical_entity.n.01'), [Synset('entity.n.01')]]],
    [Synset('organism.n.01'),
     [Synset('living_thing.n.01'),
      [Synset('whole.n.02'),
       [Synset('object.n.01'),
        [Synset('physical_entity.n.01'), [Synset('entity.n.01')]]]]]]]],
  [Synset('female.n.02'),
   [Synset('person.n.01'),
    [Synset('causal_agent.n.01'),
     [Synset('physical_entity.n.01'), [Synset('entity.n.01')]]],
    [Synset('organism.n.01'),
     [Synset('living_thing.n.01'),
      [Synset('whole.n.02'),
       [Synset('object.n.01'),
        [Synset('physical_entity.n.01'), [Synset('entity.n.01')]]]]]]]]]]
```

My goal is to represent this output in a directed graph. 
The point is that `Synset('entity.n.01')` is supposed to be the root node and that there should be a path from `Synset('girl.n.01')` to `Synset('entity.n.01')` and from `Synset('organism.n.01')` to `Synset('entity.n.01')` etc.

Is this supposed to be solved by recursion? Does anyone know a solution to go from the nested nested nested list etc. to a graph with `Synset('entity.n.01')` as the root?

Comment: Pretty sure recursion is the way to go here. You may have better luck searching for "tree" rather than "graph". I found [this link](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2773/) which appears to convert nested lists to tree output, perhaps that is helpful?

Comment: @whrrgarbl Thanks, I have figured it out. Recursion was indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I solved this not using the nltk tree method on a synsets, but rather iterated through the synonyms of a word using a recursive function

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def extract_hypernyms(sense):
    global data_list
    if(len(sense.hypernyms()) > 0):
        for hypernym in sense.hypernyms():
            data_list.append(sense)
            extract_hypernyms(hypernym)
    else:
        hypernym_tree.append([data for data in data_list])
        del data_list[:]

if __name__ =='__main__':
    hypernym_tree = list()
    data_list = []
    word = wn.synsets('avocado')[0]
    extract_hypernyms(word)
    create_path_from_nodes(hypernym_tree)
```

This returns a list of list that you iterate through.

```
[[Synset('avocado.n.01'),
  Synset('edible_fruit.n.01'),
  Synset('fruit.n.01'),
  Synset('reproductive_structure.n.01'),
  Synset('plant_organ.n.01'),
  Synset('plant_part.n.01'),
  Synset('natural_object.n.01'),
  Synset('whole.n.02'),
  Synset('object.n.01'),
  Synset('physical_entity.n.01')],
 [Synset('edible_fruit.n.01'),
  Synset('produce.n.01'),
  Synset('food.n.02'),
  Synset('solid.n.01'),
  Synset('matter.n.03'),
  Synset('physical_entity.n.01')]]
```